# Monogame fails to load Effect

Tags: shaders, monogame, graphic-effects

I'm currently porting an old XNA game over to MonoGame and everything (including custom shaders) build fine.

However when i try to load the xnb file using `content.Load<Effect>("BaseDraw");`
I receive the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll

Additional information: HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], 
    ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], Message: The parameter is incorrect.
```

I even tried building the shaders with 2MGFX.exe and loading it manually but that throws the same error.

I have no idea what to so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Figured I had the shader versions too high (`vs_5_0`/`ps_5_0`) lowering them to their `4_0` variant fixed the error.